# Horizontal Divider Line Between Floating List Items in CSS

Tags: css, css-float

I want to add line between floating items like this:

```
..........................................
.                                        .
.    LI LI LI LI LI LI LI LI LI LI LI    .
.    --------------------------------    .
.    LI LI LI LI LI LI LI LI LI LI LI    .
.    --------------------------------    .
.    LI LI LI LI LI LI*                  .
.                                        .
..........................................
```

*Notice that last list items at last row has no border/divider line.

I have pure UL/LI elements, dont want to use extra class that cause look dirty HTML and unschemantic ways.

How to accomplish this with pure CSS?

Comment: have u tried using <hr> where you want the divider line?

Comment: HR in UL?? Noway @cup_of

Comment: @Digerkam I assume that the number of <li> is not fixed per row, is that correct?

Comment: In fact, responsively it is 4 on desktop, 3 on tablet, and 2 on phone. But customer want to play with it :) @NilesTanner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can assume the elements per row you can do this with pure css

Example : http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/yaPgzj

if you had 4 li elements per width you can place a bottom border on each

```
li{
  float:left;
  width:25%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

then select the last row and remove the border.

```
li:nth-child(4n+1):nth-last-child(-n+4),
  li:nth-child(4n+1):nth-last-child(-n+4) ~ li {
    border:none;
}
```

Then it's just a matter of making media queries for each platform. if you have 3 elements per row you would change all of the 4s to 3s for example

Comment: Wow, I like that!

Comment: But what if you don't know how many li elements you will have?